# Read old data from the table, while some transaction is writing to the same table

Tags: .net, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, transactionscope, isolation-level

What I want is being able to read old data from the table, while some transaction is writing to the same table. When such atomic writing is completed, I want to replace the old data with the new one.

Transaction I'm coping with is long and I don't want enable dirty reads nor block reading possibility.

I've turned on snapshot isolation level on my database:

```
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

and used code like this to write data in transaction:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                       new TransactionOptions
                           { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
{
    update();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Unfortunately while I'm trying to read some data using `SELECT * FROM [Table]` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, query execution is waiting with message `Executing query...`, and retrieves data after transaction is completed. What I've missed ?

**EDIT:** code for update() - basically simple inserts within a loop, mixed with no db related stuff connected with WCF which slows down the process:

```
var val = Web.Download();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table]([value]) VALUES (@val)";
        command.Parameters.Add(CreateParam(command, "@val", val, DbType.String));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your update() method do exactly (please post relevant code) ? In Management Studio, running SELECT * FROM [Table] with (nolock) or SELECT * FROM [Table] with (read_uncommitted) should not hang

Comment: If I use SELECT * FROM [Table] with (nolock) I'm able to get data which are inserted while code within transaction scope is still ongoing. After abort, where transaction rolls back, such data disappears. So in my understanding I was able to do dirty read which is what I want to avoid. I want to read only old consistent state. I want the new data to be available for read only after commit.

Comment: Then I guess you should use SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON; ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179599%28v=sql.105%29.aspx ) or proceed as suggested by @flup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the isolation level for your select too.
Before your `SELECT * FROM [Table]`, add `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Thanks, setting this isolation level before SELECT returns saved data from snapshot. Do you know why isn't it the default behavior while I'm selecting the data from table, while transaction is ongoing for such table and its snapshot exists ?

Comment: The default isolation level is Read committed.